General protection fault when initializing mouse driver
I'm writing an x86_64 os and testing it on qemu pc. I'm trying to implement a mouse driver, but when I reach the end of the initialization function, I get a general protection fault. Another wierd thing that happens which I'm not sure is normal is that all call to wait_mouse end up timeouting (for testing purpouses I ignore the timeout, also because that is what the code I took did). Here is my code (which seems to be what every single hobby kernel online uses):
const MOUSE_PORT: u16 = 0x60;
const MOUSE_STATUS: u16 = 0x64;
const MOUSE_ABIT: u8 = 0x02;
const MOUSE_BBIT: u8 = 0x01;
const MOUSE_WRITE: u8 = 0xD4;
const MOUSE_F_BIT: u16 = 0x20;
const MOUSE_V_BIT: u16 = 0x08;

pub fn init() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let mut status: u8 = 0;

    unsafe {
        asm!("cli");
    }
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_STATUS, 0xA8);
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_STATUS, 0x20);
    mouse_wait(false)?;
    status = inb(0x60) | 2;
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_STATUS, 0x60);
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_PORT, status);
    mouse_write(0xF6)?;
    mouse_read()?;
    mouse_write(0xF4)?;
    mouse_read()?;
    unsafe {
        asm!("sti");
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn mouse_wait(a_type: bool) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    let mut timeout = 100000;
    if !a_type {
        while timeout > 0 {
            if inb(MOUSE_STATUS) & MOUSE_BBIT == 1 {
                return Ok(());
            }
            timeout -= 1;
        }
    } else {
        while timeout > 0 {
            if inb(MOUSE_STATUS) & MOUSE_ABIT != 0 {
                return Ok(());
            }
            timeout -= 1;
        }
    }
    // Err("Mouse timeout")
    Ok(())
}

fn mouse_write(write: u8) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_STATUS, MOUSE_WRITE);
    mouse_wait(true)?;
    outb(MOUSE_PORT, write);
    Ok(())
}

fn mouse_read() -> Result<u8, &'static str> {
    mouse_wait(false)?;
    Ok(inb(MOUSE_PORT))
}

I looked at the instruction pointed to by the RIP saved by the general protection fault, and it appears to be a pop instruction right before the ret of the initialization routine.
Here is what I get from qemu:
Servicing hardware INT=0x21
   221: v=21 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:000000000e097a07 pc=000000000e097a07 SP=0010:000000000fe96770 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=0000000002cbb000 RCX=00000000000186a0 RDX=00000000801b0060
RSI=000000000e0a9118 RDI=0000000000000064 RBP=000000000fe96801 RSP=000000000fe96770
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000064 R13=000000000e98d000 R14=0000111100000000 R15=000000000fe967a8
RIP=000000000e097a07 RFL=00000246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0028 000000000e0ae151 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     000000000e0af2e8 00000037
IDT=     000000000e0ae1c8 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000449000 CR4=00000668
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000001 CCD=0000000000000001 CCO=CLR
EFER=0000000000000d00
Servicing hardware INT=0x24
   222: v=24 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:000000000e097a07 pc=000000000e097a07 SP=0010:000000000fe96770 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=0000000002cbb000 RCX=00000000000186a0 RDX=00000000801b0060
RSI=000000000e0a9118 RDI=0000000000000064 RBP=000000000fe96801 RSP=000000000fe96770
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000064 R13=000000000e98d000 R14=0000111100000000 R15=000000000fe967a8
RIP=000000000e097a07 RFL=00000246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0028 000000000e0ae151 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     000000000e0af2e8 00000037
IDT=     000000000e0ae1c8 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000449000 CR4=00000668
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000044 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000d00
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
   223: v=0d e=0122 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:000000000e097a07 pc=000000000e097a07 SP=0010:000000000fe96770 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=0000000002cbb000 RCX=00000000000186a0 RDX=00000000801b0060
RSI=000000000e0a9118 RDI=0000000000000064 RBP=000000000fe96801 RSP=000000000fe96770
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000064 R13=000000000e98d000 R14=0000111100000000 R15=000000000fe967a8
RIP=000000000e097a07 RFL=00000246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0028 000000000e0ae151 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     000000000e0af2e8 00000037
IDT=     000000000e0ae1c8 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000449000 CR4=00000668
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000044 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000d00

I set the interrupt service routine at 44 (32 + 12) before calling the init function. At the moment it just prints "mouse!" and loops forever, without sending any EOI (which shouldn't be needed). Are there mabye any other ps2 configurations I need to do before calling init? Thanks for the help!

Is the faulting pop a pop rbp after a mov rsp, rbp or something?  Perhaps you overwrote the saved RBP somehow so the stack pointer is now bogus?  Is this running as a UEFI application so you already started in 64-bit mode, or legacy 16-bit BIOS and you had to set up a GDT and page tables and switch to 64-bit mode?

The instruction is pop rcx, so my guess is it is not a stack pointer issue, also because I'm not touching those in this function. I'm running after exiting UEFI boot services. I have setup and IDT, a GDT and the PIC

Maybe set a breakpoint and look at RSP on function entry, and make sure it's about the same at the pop rcx.  If not, something broke your stack pointer.  If it is the same, then something unmapped your stack memory.  LLVM likes to use pop rcx as an optimization for add rsp, 8 with optimization enabled, and RCX is a call-clobbered register, so this is not a save/restore, it's just about keeping RSP aligned by 16 before any calls in this function and restoring it before ret.

The only two inline assembly I'm using is for sti and cli, so the stack shouldn't be corrupted. Could it be possible my qemu system has a different device at those io addresses and therefore writing data there causes some kind of fault?

Yeah, I don't know how the stack pointer or stack mapping could have gotten corrupted, especially not with a GPF instead of a page fault.  But that's why you should use a debugger to investigate, perhaps Bochs with its built-in debugger that can decode/dump page tables and GDT so you can see if they're what you wanted.  Maybe your stack overlaps your page tables or something?

If using the I/O port was causing a fault, I'd have expected it to be delivered with RIP pointing at an out or in instruction, not a pop.  First figure out why you get a GPF with that RIP.  On possible cause of GPF is a non-canonical address (high 16 bits don't match bit #47, i.e. not a 48-bit address sign-extended to 64).  So look at RSP.  I don't know what else could cause a GPF on a pop, especially if we assume that there were earlier instructions that wrote and read stack memory in this function.  Maybe it's the first use of RSP after an interrupt or other trap?

The GPF happens after I re enable the interrupts with sti. The interrupt handler is already registered an I tested it works. Also, note the thing I mentioned about the mouse wait timing out. Could this have something to do with it?

Oh, the pop rcx is the instruction right after sti?  Then yeah it's probably some problem in handling an external interrupt.  I don't know enough PS/2 or interrupt-handling stuff to see a problem from just looking at your code, but you might be able to find something in the #GP fault code (like #GP(0) vs. some other number).

I updated the post with what you asked

The problem is this I think: 228: v=20 v=20 (0x20) is the timer interrupt. The exception after has v=0d has an error e=102 (0x102). 0x102 for the GPF means that there was a problem while trying to use  the interrupt 0x20 via the IDT. My question is do you have a handler for the timer? If you don't you need to create one and set the IDT or you need to mask off all the interrupts n the PICs you don't want to receive.

If you have a timer handler in the IDT you should see if all the bits are set appropriately in it. There is some issue with the entry from what I can tell. It could be related to privilege, type, limit, read/write rights bits..

Sorry, I disabled the timer in the IDT because the timer interrupts were drowning out the GP exception. Now, I masked the timer interrupt in the PIC (as I should have before). I updated my post with the GP exception that happens after initializing the mouse

But I'm not pressing any keys, and when I don't call the mouse init function, the GP fault doesn't happen

If you scroll down you'll see the GP fault

Okay so you get a keyboard interrupt v=21 (maybe left over from initializing the PS/2 keyboard controller?). That keyboard interrupt didn't cause a fault. Then you got v=24 which is IRQ4 (Serial port com1). The exception v=0d with e=122 is GPF with a selector error using selector 0x24 in the IDT table. I am guessing you don't have a serial port handler/IDT entry?

You are correct. I now tried masking all interrupts except for keyboard, slave pic and mouse. I still get a 0x24 interrupt firing. Why could this be? Also why would the serial port involved?

How are you masking them off (what interrupt bitmask value did you use to the master and slave PICs? If done properly you shouldn't be receiving serial port interrupts. I can't say why you are getting something from com1 . Did you hook up QEMU to the first serial port using the command line?

I didn't. Here is how I'm masking the:
outb(MASTER_PIC_DATA, !0b110);
outb(SLAVE_PIC_DATA, !0b10000);

While looking at your repository (not sure how old it is compared to what you are using) I see this remap_pic(32, 32 + 7); in pic8259.rs. You should be using remap_pic(32, 32 + 8);

Thank you SO much! I'm an idiot, I probably typed it wrong and never noticed it because I wasn't using any slave pic interrupt. You saved my life! now the interrupts are firing
